# Code completion in Android Studio : completion overwrites

Tags: android-studio, code-completion

There is this feature that Eclipse had.

Assuming you are summoning the code-completion in the middle of a word, the IDE it's giving you the possibility to configure if the suggested completion is just inserted (default Android Studio behavior) or it should overwrite the entire word/expression.

Is there a similar configuration in Android Studio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If, instead of pressing `Enter` to make your code completion selection, you use `Tab` then the code completion will overwrite what is at the caret, rather than just inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio - completion overwrites**

Mac 
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Windows 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

<kbd>Enter</kbd> - to **insert** a suggestion 
<kbd>Tab</kbd> - to **overwrite** a suggestion